# Customize Magento modules

Tags: magento-1.7

I am new in magento. I have install SMS Text Messaging - powered by 24x module in magento but I want to customize this module and want to embed mvaayoo php api and remove 24x code. Please tell me how to Customize Magento modules and proper flow structure of the magento files.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

To understand magento module development or customize existing modules(including directory structure) you may visit following links:

http://knowledge.santanu.net/developer-guide-for-magento-module-structure-and-codepool/
http://knowledge.santanu.net/magento-mvc-pattern-and-advanced-module-development-guide/